# creating a custom function to replace values in R

Tags: r, function, if-statement, matrix, replace

I would like to replace some values in a matrix using a custom function. What I want to do is to create a function called "replace.mixed" that replaces, specifically,  "7 to 0" and "8 and 9 to NA". I tried the following but it did not work.

```
"replace.mixed" <- function (x) {
if(x = 7) {x == 0}
if(x == 8 || 9) {x == NA}
}

### test function
data <- matrix(1:12,3,4) # create a matrix
replace.mixed(data)
```

I would appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: `if` works on a single value, `ifelse` is vectorized. `x == 8 || 9` will be parsed as `(x == 8)` first, which will be TRUE or FALSE, then the result from that "OR 9". You want `x == 8 | x == 9`, or more simply, `x %in% c(8, 9)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `ifelse`

```
 replace.mixed <- function(x) {
  x[] <- ifelse(x==7, 0, ifelse(x %in% c(8,9), NA, x))
 x}

 replace.mixed(data)
 #     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 #[1,]    1    4    0   10
 #[2,]    2    5   NA   11
 #[3,]    3    6   NA   12
```

This could be also code-golfed

```
(data!=7)*data *NA^(data %in% 8:9)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    4    0   10
#[2,]    2    5   NA   11
#[3,]    3    6   NA   12
```

Comment: The second one is neat.

Comment: That's nearly bug-worthy that `NA^0 == 1` isn't it? I get the logic but shouldn't `NA` with any arithmetic operator be `NA`?

Comment: @thelatemail Yes, it could have bugs.

Comment: @akrun Worked well! Thanks!

Comment: @thelatemail Agreed, seems like if `NA * 0 == NA` (it is), then `NA ^ 0` should also be `NA`.

Comment: `NA` is logical so it's unknown with possible values of `0` or `1` once coerced to numeric. `0^0` and `0^1` are both `1` so `NA^0` is not unknown, it has to be `1`. I agree it seems odd but it makes complete sense and should stay that way.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `which()` to index.

```
data[which(data == 7)] <- 0
data[which(data == 8 | data == 9)] <- NA
data
[,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    4    0   10
[2,]    2    5   NA   11
[3,]    3    6   NA   12
```

The function using `which()`would be:

```
replace<-function(x){
    x[which(x == 7)]<-0
    x[which(x == 8 | x == 9)]<-NA
  return(x)
  }
```

Hope this would be helpful.

Comment: Title of the thread: "creating a custom **function** to replace values in R"

Comment: Added as a function.

Comment: @MikeFang Worked! Thanks for your time!

Answer (score -1):

Try the below code

```
 replaced.mixed<-function(x){
  if(x==7) {x==0}
  else if(x==8 || x==9) {x='NA'}
  else x
}
data<-matrix(1:12,3,4)
data1<-matrix(,3,4)
x<-replaced.mixed(data[1,1])
for (i in 1:3){
  for (j in 1:4){
    data1[i,j]<-replaced.mixed(data[i,j])
  }
}
```

Comment: So it is the same function as the OP?

Comment: What is the purpose of the double-`for` loop?

Comment: The function was for one number, and you were applying it for the matrix,
so you need to go by each cell of the matrix (that's why double for loop), so you need loop for that

Comment: Well I am not the OP

Comment: @PrabodhHend Thanks for your time. I think the first part including the function is enough. It works with my test function. Why did you create a dataset with all NAs (by data1<-matrix(,3,4)) ?